# Wordpress Mysql Delete post if title contains

Tags: mysql

I want to delete all of my wordpress posts, which contains specific keywords. In regex it would be:

```
.+\((S\d+E\d+)\)
```

for example it would delete:

```
"Post blabla (S01E02)"
"1231 How to do it (S55E02)
"(S05E72)"
```

But i dont know how to use regexp in mysql properly. Can you help me with that. I think, something like this would be good:

```
SELECT * FROM 'wp_posts';
WHERE 'post_title' REGEXP '__i dont know what to put there__';
```

Comment: `.+` in beginning means that there should be at least a character before `(` starts. So "(S05E72)" wouldn't qualify for this. I think you just meant `\((S\d+E\d+)\)`

Answer (score 0):

Seems like this should do it:

```
REGEXP "\\(S[0-9]+E[0-9]+\\)";
```

Add a `$` to the end if you want to matches in the last position only.

Comment: Note that @Ham Burg asked for \d+. I think you just missed that

Comment: Hmm.. i can select post properly, but when i try to delete i have that error: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '* FROM wp_posts WHERE post_title REGEXP '\(S[0-9]+E[0-9]+\)'' at line 1

Comment: What's the full query? Seems weird that MySQL would report an error starting on the `*`

Comment: When i use `SELECT * FROM wp_posts WHERE post_title REGEXP '\\(S[0-9]+E[0-9]+\\)'` I've properly getting over 7000 rows. But when i use `DELETE * FROM wp_posts WHERE post_title REGEXP '\\(S[0-9]+E[0-9]+\\)'` as I said, I've getting error: `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '* FROM wp_posts WHERE post_title REGEXP '\\(S[0-9]+E[0-9]+\\)'' at line 1 `

Comment: There's no `*` in delete; it's just `delete from mytable where ...`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working example with some negative test cases: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/edc50/2

```
SELECT * FROM wp_posts WHERE post_title REGEXP '\\(S[0-9]+E[0-9]+\\)';
```

Comment: Hmm.. i can select post properly, but when i try to delete i have that error: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '* FROM wp_posts WHERE post_title REGEXP '\\(S[0-9]+E[0-9]+\\)'' at line 1